# git add + git commit again after fixing a coding mistake from last git add + git commit

Tags: git

I did git add + git commit to a file. I had my code reviewed and I found a mistake, so I fixed the mistake and did git add + git commit again on the same file.

Now if I git push, will only my correct & 2nd change/commit affect the production repo? I am worried and want to make sure that the production code will only change to be my correct code/commit!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "affect". Both commits will be in the production repo but maybe only the second one is ever built.